# onCurrentAccessTokenChanged called multiple times during logout from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to add a callback method when successfully logging out of Facebook because the onSuccess method seems to only get called when logging in. I got the following block of code elsewhere on here:

```
private AccessTokenTracker fbTracker;
...
fbTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken2) {
                if (accessToken2 == null) {


                    Log.d(TAG, "User Logged Out.");

                    mEditor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_FACEBOOK_LOGIN, false);
                    mEditor.commit();
                    Log.d(TAG, "fbLoginButton success");

                    String msg = "Facebook successfully logged out";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    customFbLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    customFbLogoutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };
```

And in logcat I see:

```
D/LoginActivity: User Logged Out.
D/LoginActivity: fbLoginButton success
D/LoginActivity: User Logged Out.
D/LoginActivity: fbLoginButton success
D/LoginActivity: User Logged Out.
D/LoginActivity: fbLoginButton success
D/LoginActivity: User Logged Out.
D/LoginActivity: fbLoginButton success
D/LoginActivity: User Logged Out.
D/LoginActivity: fbLoginButton success
D/LoginActivity: User Logged Out.
D/LoginActivity: fbLoginButton success
```

In this case, I don't think it is doing any harm, but I would like to try to fix it if I can. Is this behavior avoidable?

Answer (score 1):

In your lifecycle, you have to disable and enable this object fbTracker.
For instance, this method stopTracking() can be called when your activity is paused etc...
You can restart it at anytime.